# How can I prepare a statement like the following using PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_agent";

if (isset($_POST["submit"]))    {
    $srch = htmlspecialchars($_POST["search_user"]);
    $sql .= " WHERE ";

    if (empty($srch))   {
        $sql = "";
    } else
    {
        $sql .= "login LIKE '%{$srch}%' OR lastname LIKE '%{$srch}%' OR email LIKE '%{$srch}%' OR firstname LIKE '%{$srch}%'";
    }
}
```

I would like to change all my procedural queries with PDO queries. I have the above code which searches for a number of variables and uses wildcards. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you prepare the statement?

Answer (score 0):

How to create PDO conntection : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Your example query

```
$srch = 'something';
$srch2 = 'otherthing';

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM cc_agent WHERE login LIKE :srch OR lastname LIKE :srch2');
$sth->bindParam(':srch', '%'.$srch.'%');
$sth->bindParam(':srch2', '%'.$srch2.'%');
$sth->execute();
```

More usefull resources about bindParam:http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))    {
    $srch = htmlspecialchars($_POST["search_user"]);
    $sql .= " WHERE ";

    if (empty($srch))   {
        $sql = "";
    } else
    {
        $sql .= "login LIKE ? OR lastname LIKE ? OR email LIKE ? OR firstname LIKE ?";
    }
}
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($srch, $srch, $srch, $srch));


while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))   {
    extract($row);
    echo $variable1, $variable2;
}
```

Thanks for the help guys. Tried the above code and it works perfectly. Cheers!